# Adding an image inside a custom dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made my own drop down here: http://jsfiddle.net/Hunter4854/GJVjT/ I am trying to add a image to the left of the words PS3. I need to add separate images to the left of each `<li>`. I have tried everything i know, but can not find out the problem?

Comment: Didn't you ask this question already

Comment: What is the actual problem? I don't see any code trying to add images

Comment: @Musa opps...i am sorry, i did...oh and what did you edit in that other code...that you had the jsfiddle for? i could not find where you had changed anything.

Comment: @Musa What bit of code did you take out? I did not see where you had taken anything out....It worked though, if you would post the answer here, with the code you added or deleted, than i will accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rebuilt the custom list html in this code:

```
$('#test_select option').each(function(i){
    html.push('<li rel="'+$(this).val() +'">'+$(this).text()+'</li>');
});
$('.custom-select ul').html(html.join(''))
```

so whatever predefined HTML you put was replaced by it.

To fix, you do one of the following:

- [you allow the predefined HTML to show](http://jsfiddle.net/GJVjT/3/)
- [or create the image in the code](http://jsfiddle.net/GJVjT/1/)